# Best algorithm on checking a node in a tree path?

Tags: c#, algorithm, path, tree

Suppose I have this tree :

```
           O-ROOT
         /        \
    O-A            O-B
     /          /       \
O-A1        O-B1        O-B2
```

and I want to do this in C#:

```
1. Check every node starting from root (I think the best way is trought recursion?);
2. If I found a node with value = "Hello", return true and STOP the searching function;
```

Can you help me to make the best algorithm for doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right with the recursion, see [depth-first](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/depth_breadth_search.htm) or breadth-first search algorithm. It is much easier for trees since you don't have keep list of already visited nodes.

```
public bool Search(TreeNode node, string searchString)
{
   if(node.Value == searchString) return true;
   foreach(var childNode in node.Children)
     if(Search(childNode, searchString)) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach for your problem will be to use [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). It is simple to write and as effective as you can get.

EDIT: something like this:

```
public bool Search(TreeNode node, string searchString)
{
   Queue<Control> q = new Queue<Node>();
   q.Enqueue(node);
   while(!q.empty()) {
     Node current = q.Dequeue();
     foreach(var childNode in node.Children)
       if(childNode.Content.CompareTo(searchString) == 0) {
         return true;
       }
       q.Enqueue(childNode);
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: For searching in trees depth-first is better - no additional collections, recursion only (and recursion is the DFS way;)

Comment: My experience teaches me otherwise. The problem with dfs is that for high trees it will cause stack overflow.

Comment: I think so, too. You should only use recursion if you can be sure that the recursion depth is somewhat known and low enough - as well as not going to change.

Comment: Why do you think BFS ist better? DFS can also be implemented without recursion and typically uses much less memory.

Comment: @Henrik the only way to implement DFS without recursion is by simulating the stack and that takes a lot more effort then simple BFS. Also I don't think it will ever take less memory. I have been doing computer science competitions for more then 10 years and I prefer BFS most of the time for good reasons.

Comment: @izomorphius - just replace the Queue in your code by a Stack and you have DFS. How does this "take a lot more effort"?

Comment: @izomorphius your current code contains a queue as well a recursive call.

Comment: @Christian yes I adapted it from another answer I have fixed it. Thank you

Comment: @Henrik - yes replacing the queue with a stack will result in a DFS, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool FindHello(Node node)
{
    if (node.Content == "Hello")
        return true;
    foreach (Node c in node.Children)
        if (FindHello(c))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) are amongst the most popular (amongst others) tree searching techniques, so you can started from there. Also, if each node in your tree will have at most 2 nodes and they are sorted in some way, you could use [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) Techniques.

Answer (score 0):

1. Indeed, definitely use recursion for this.
2. If you are using a recursive method you can set a (static) member variable like result and check each iteration if it's set. If set, just jump out of the method (return) to stop the recursion running further.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to NOT use recursion! You do not know, how deep the tree is, and if it is too deep, you will get a stack overflow because of too many recursion levels. Do a Breadth-first-search or depth-first-search. Also have a look at in-order, post-order and pre-order traversal techniques. Since this is probably a homework / lecture task, it will be good to look those keywords up.

Comment: It is not a homework. I'm building a Menu on C# for a my own project. Yeah, it won't have 10000 items, but is always better optimize stuff into a project :) Why not recursion? Breadth-first-search or depth-first use it :O

Comment: BFS/DFS do not necessarily use it. You can code both in an iterative way. Recursion is a nice and neat thing, however you have to always be aware that A) method calls cost performance (altough not much) and B) you cannot recurse endlessly. If you definately have less than 10000 items, you can savely use recursion. But if you are writing a more general tree traversal library(?) - just an example - you need to consider the depth of the tree